# An application of convergence of measures

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure, stochastic-calculus, weak-convergence

I am looking for an "easy" reference on the convergence of measures applied to the following:

I have a probability space $(\Omega_n, \mathcal{F}_n, P_n)$ where $\Omega_n$ is countably finite of size $n^2$ and $P_n$ is the counting measure.

I define a random variable on this probability space
$X_n:\Omega_n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$

Assume that $\sum_{\omega\in \Omega_{n}}\mathbb{1}\{X_n(\omega)=1\}\leq n$.

Notice:
$$
P_n(\{\omega\in \Omega_n \text{ s.t. } X_n(\omega)=1\})\equiv \frac{\sum_{\omega\in \Omega_{n}}\mathbb{1}\{X_n(\omega)=1\}}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n}
$$

---

I am looking for a mathematical framework/result/notion (if it makes any sense) stating that the measure

$$
\frac{\sum_{\omega\in \Omega_{n}}\mathbb{1}\{X_n(\omega)=1\}}{n^2}
$$
(or maybe a rescaled version?) "converges" to  a Lebesgue integral as $n\rightarrow \infty $.

---

I am very confused because
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{\omega\in \Omega_{n}}\mathbb{1}\{X_n(\omega)=1\}}{n^2} =0
$$
which leads me to think that I have to rescale, but beyond that I don't see what I should do.

---

Could you guide me towards some "easy" reference? I have read about weak or vague convergence of measures but it looks too wide and I can't read the whole topic in order to answer my doubt.

Comment: You have not specified what $X_n(\omega)$ is for each $n$, other than saying it is binary-valued and its sum over $\omega$ is no more than $n$.  Why should you expect convergence of any kind, beyond the obvious $n/n^2\rightarrow 0$? You might as well be asking "If $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an integer-valued sequence that satisfies $0 \leq y_n \leq n$ for all $n$, then what can be said about convergence of re-scaled versions of $y_n/n^2$?"  [Indeed for any such $\{y_n\}$ sequence we can construct corresponding $X_n(\omega)$ such that $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega_n} 1\{X_n(\omega)=1\} = y_n$. ]